# ¿Cómo hacer para que la toolbar quede fija en Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, toolbar

Tengo un problema con la toolbar, cuando se despliega el teclado para ingresar un valor numérico en un EditText, éste empuja todo el contenido hacia arriba ocultando la toolbar y el FloatingActionButton.

Me gustaría que estos 2 elementos mantuvieran su posicion. ¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.leonus96.joseph.cocomobasico.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_calcular" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que comentas es un comportamiento normal e inteligente del widget, si el EditText es enfocado, se muestra el teclado virtual pero no se muestra sobre al EditText, en cuanto al ToolBar y el FloatingActionButton estos se mueven hacia arriba para mantener un layout uniforme.

Lo que se puede realizar en este caso es agregar un ScrollView contenedor, el cual contendría tus EditText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.leonus96.joseph.cocomobasico.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</ScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_calcular" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```